# How to Enable NEON in OpenCV by using ndk-build on Android Platform?

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, arm, neon

I am new to Android platform. I have already included openCV library in my c++ code and successfully built an .so file by using ndk-build command. The app has already successfully run on my android phone. My question is how to enable NEON for a better performance? I have already included "LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true" in my .mk file but it did not seem to work. I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: undeclared crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-enable-neon-in-opencv-by-using-ndk-build-on-android-platform/12004

Comment: Are you targeting arm7 or arm8? It seems by default OpenCV for arm64-v8a will enable Neon, while armeabi-v7a will not. Are you building OpenCV yourself?